# Is this equation for the rotational weight of a half disk correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, rotational-dynamics

I need to know what rotational force the weight of this disk applies to the axle.

[image: Half disk mounted on a rod.]

I'm not sure what the units are, whether it's torque or something else I'm looking for. The weight of the disk is $z\frac{\pi r^2}{2}$ where $z$ is the thickness however I'm only looking for the rotational force thus ignoring the weight that is supported by the axle.

After a lot of thinking I came up with the integral:

$$z\int_{0}^{r} \int_{0}^{\pi} r^2 \sin(\theta)  d\theta dr=z\frac{2r^3}{3}$$

Later I found the equation for the center of mass of a half disk: $\frac{4r}{3\pi}$ and when multiplied by the mass of the disk it equates to the same answer: $z\frac{\pi r^2}{2}\frac{4r}{3\pi}=z\frac{2r^3}{3}$

I'm not perfectly sure what I have here but my intuition tells me that a scale at the tip of a rod of length $1$ would measure $z\frac{2r^3}{3}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **volume** of the disk is $z\frac{\pi r^2}{2}$ not the weight. Otherwise you have done everything correctly! :)

Here's how I solved your problem, it's very similar to your solution but keeps track of the directions involved (and doesn't require any integration). Apologies if this does not clarify things.

[The rotational force or torque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque) ($\tau$) is equivalent to the weight ($\vec{F}$) acting at the [center of mass/gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass) multiplied by the distance to the center of mass ($\vec{d}$).
$$
\vec{\tau} = \vec{d} \times \vec{F} 
$$
The force is from the weight of the disk and in the downwards direction
$$
\vec{F} = -mg \ \hat y = - \rho V g \ \hat y = - \frac{1}{2}\rho z\pi r^2 g \ \hat y
$$
The distance from the axis to the center of mass is, like you said, given by $\vec{d}=\frac{4r}{3\pi} \ \hat{x}$. Therefore the torque
$$
\vec{\tau} = (\frac{4r}{3\pi}) \ \hat{x} \times (- \frac{1}{2}\rho z\pi r^2 g) \ \hat y \\
= -\frac{2r^3 \rho z g}{3} \hat z
$$
The magnitude of the torque is like how strong the turning force is, and the direction of the torque is perpendicular to both $F$ and $r$. If this concept is new to you, I suggest reading up on [cross products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) and [torque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque).